# MongoDB Insecure Startup for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I installed MongoDB via Brew and now I get this error:

> “/Library/StartupItems/MongoDB” has not been started because it does not have the proper security settings

[image]

I've repaired permissions, reinstalled, and it doesn't go away. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of OS X (since Snow Leopard IIRC) are pickier about the permissions on things like startupitems, and will disable them if it thinks they're inappropriate.  This should set the permissions it's looking for:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/StartupItems/MongoDB
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /Library/StartupItems/MongoDB
sudo chmod -R -N /Library/StartupItems/MongoDB
```

Comment: `chmod: Invalid file mode: u:rwX,go=rX`

Comment: Typo; should be `u=...` (I've fixed it above)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to remove the Startup item, here is a solution: [Apple Support Site](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3493)

Comment: I don't want to remove the Startup Item as I want MongoDB to load on startup